# Can $x$ take every value here?

Tags: determinant

To find $x$ such that this determinant is zero, a,b,c are distinct and real constants.
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    x-a & a^2 & a^3 \\
    x-b & b^2 & b^3 \\
    x-c & c^2 & c^3 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
=0$$

I get that it can be done by row operations and further simplification. But I don't understand why  my 300 IQ move does not get the right answer.

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    \frac xa-1 & a^3 & a^3 \\
    \frac xb-1 & b^3 & b^3 \\
    \frac xc-1 & c^3 & c^3 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
 $$

Two columns now being the same implies the determinant is zero. So x can take any number ??

Comment: You might have to explain what this operation is, and why you think the determinant below is related to the determinant above.

Comment: @TheoBendit I took "a,b,c" from one column and gave it to another

Comment: And which rule about determinants justifies that operation?

Comment: Btw, there is a simple way to sort out such a problem: Choose concrete values for $a, b, c$ and evaluate both determinants. Then compare the results.

Comment: @MartinR I learnt it in class :/

Comment: @Linkin That's perfectly fine for one constant. You could divide the first column by $a$, and multiply the second by $a$, but you can't do this for $3$ different constants, selectively by row, all at the same time.

Comment: I still don't understand your operation. If we look at the first row, it seems like you have **divided** the first element and **multiplied** the rest of the elements by $a$.

Comment: @TheoBendit crab, thanks!

Comment: @Linkin You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no row operation that can get you from

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
    x-a & a^2 & a^3 \\
    x-b & b^2 & b^3 \\
    x-c & c^2 & c^3 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

To

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    \frac xa-1 & a^3 & a^3 \\
    \frac xb-1 & b^3 & b^3 \\
    \frac xc-1 & c^3 & c^3 \\
    \end{vmatrix}.
 $$

For one, the first determinant is defined for all values $a,b,c$, while the second one is only defined for nonzero values of $a,b,c$, so the two expression are clearly not equal.

But even on regions where both expressions are defined, they are not equal. You can verify this by plugging in $x=0, a=1, b=2, c=3$ in which case you get

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
    x-a & a^2 & a^3 \\
    x-b & b^2 & b^3 \\
    x-c & c^2 & c^3 \\
    \end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & 1 \\
    -2 & 4 & 8 \\
    -3 & 9 & 27 \\
    \end{vmatrix} = -12
$$

and

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    \frac xa-1 & a^3 & a^3 \\
    \frac xb-1 & b^3 & b^3 \\
    \frac xc-1 & c^3 & c^3 \\
    \end{vmatrix} = 0
 $$

and since $0\neq 12$, the two determinants are clearly not the same.

---

I don't know what "rule" you used to get from one expression to the other, but what I can tell you is that you either did not use the rule correctly, or you used a rule that is not really a rule.